# Cheap machine with Xen to have more than one personal dev servers with RAID option?

Tags: virtualization, raid, xen

I do not have a lot of money so when I need a personal dev servers I decided I will use Xen on one machine to run various OS's. Although, I really like Dell Zino (http://www.dell.com/us/en/home/desktops/inspiron-zino-hd/pd.aspx?refid=inspiron-zino-hd&cs=19&s=dhs) as a very economical and compact PC which can be scaled to 8GB of RAM, I do not know how to have a RAID setup, for the failover.

Is there an economical way to add a RAID setup to Dell Zino or I would have to invest in a proper box for that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

**Also, please let me know if this question is not meant for this forum.

Comment: You're in the right place for questions like this.

Comment: Does a personal development machine need raid failover? Uptime is less critical I would imagine? I run all my dev servers as virtual machines on my workstation, which is a single drive machine. I would have though a good backup procedure is more important that uptime in this instance.

Comment: @ micmcg: You make sense, backing up can be economical also...hook up one external hard drive that.

But I was hoping if there could be a way to have RAID failover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BAD hardware choice, if you ask me.

- Get something custom build.
- Use an AMD chip on a micro-ATX board. Some of them support up to 16gb RAM. This gives you some scalability. Go for an AMD X4 or one of the soon coming X6.
- Given the proper case, you can put in a nice 4x2.5" hard disc tray. Use on board RAID as you please.
- Given a LOT more money (I went that way) and the proper case, you can use a SuperMicro SAS tray - 2x5.25" takes 8x2.5". Spend even more money ona RAID controller (I went that way - ouch) and you even get decent performance out of it ;) Especially if you spend even more money (I did that- but not on that machine) and get high performance discs).
- Given a little more money there is a nice 3.5" to 2x2.5" tray you can also use - for backup drives (i.e. to put in a 750gb 2.5" and back your stuff up onto it).

Anyhow, the micro-atx-approach has various advantages:

- It is a lot more expandable. The Zino thing is just TOO small. It is cheap, but the moment you run into the limit there, you basically can use it for somethin else.
- It is a lot more future proof. As in: buy quality components and you can basically keep the server current many years, replacing components as you go.
- 8gb RAM may not be enough. 16gb gives you the max you can have at the moment without going too expensive board wise. But 8GB - for a number of VM's - may simply not be enough.

Comment: Wow! I wanted to have my own custom build. What do you think will be an approx. cost of a system with:

micro-ATX board
AMD X4 
16gb RAM
4x2.5" hard disc array

Any companies you can suggest are good and economical at the same time?

Comment: Well, companies - no. We really do custom builds in that I order the parts and put them together with a colleague. It does not take special skill. I also prefer to go with high quality - not cheap. Like power supply etc. As tips... Wait for the AMD X6 to come in a month or so - 6 cores + boost = great for virtualization. COntrary to Intel ALL modern AMD support hardware virtualization.

Comment: Boards: RIGHT NOW I Would go for a MSI 890GXM-G65 - but I mostly wait whether the business class boards come in a month. I hope so. A cheap 4x2.5" tray that goes into a 5.25" slot costs about 30 USD or so - http://www.addonics.com/products/raid_system/ae4rcs25nsa.asp. Software RAID from your OS.

Comment: Depending on your needs to really as high on RAM As you can - this ü disc IO is your likely bottleneck. My next computer (which will also serve as workstation + hyper-v travl server) will go with WD 320gb Scorpio black drives. Decent performance.

Comment: For the case: MAke sure you have 2x5.25" bays WITHOUT ANYTHING BETWEEN THEM. THis allows you later to put in a double height 8x2.5" tray should the need arrive. Bad if there is a 0.25" space between the two slots then. Aerocool QX2000, Sharkoon Temptation are decent cases from the looks. I may get a Temptation for my media center, actually.

Comment: Last word - depending how much you plan running on that machine, spending a lot of money on hard discs may be needed. Basically, if you do virtualization, IO IS YOUR PROBLEM. I have a larger system (32gb now, soon 64) that uses D VElociraptors - expensiv, but fast. But my smaller stuff really gets away using the wD Scorpio blacks.

Comment: Now custom build - any computer sho should be able to do so. It really is simple. YOu possibly can put together your own computer by getting the parts, or have a friend who can help you. THis is "put things together", not "build something". And remember - a power supply is crucial. No joke - get something decent here ;) I like enermax.

Comment: Wow! you have really nailed it down to the details. Really liked your response. You have convinced me to build my own rather than buying from Dell, HP etc. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

RAID is not Backup. Backup is an external hard drive, or backup tape, or online service, or whatever (but it's not in the computer itself in any case).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the failover.

Comment: If you're going with a Zeno your only RAID-ish option is an external enclosure. For instance http://www.google.com/products/catalog?cid=12137502445307461131

Comment: I agree. I saw those later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Xen with multiple OSes including Windows, you will need to get a system with hardware virtualisation support - vmx in the case of AMD. It seems that only the 6850e processor option has that supported according to [this](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%20Neo%20X2%206850e%20-%20ADJ6850IAA5DO.html) site. That may factor into your purchase.

Also, the casing only has enough space to put a single hard-disk in it. So, any internal RAID setup would not work. But the good thing is that it comes with two e-SATA ports that allow you to plug an external storage array to it. There are some products that take multiple SATA disks and sticks them in an enclosure with e-SATA connections.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see that with Zino I might have to buy additional hardware for RAID. Just trying to figure out how much would that cost. If the cost is comparable to a custom build, I should go with the custom build, according to the answer below.